# sqlite insert or replace datagridview C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagridview

Regarding the Sqlite insert or replace command.

I am doing the insert if does not exist.
The inserted/updated values come from the datagridview bound to a datatable. 
The datatable has a TID column which is the primary key. It also has other columns like Tname,TUtility....

For update statement TID has a value and works well. But for an insert statement I want the serial number(which is the TID column) to be automatically populated.

```
         private void SaveData(DataGridView dgv)
            {
                using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connString))
                {

                    conn.Open();
                    dt = dt.GetChanges();
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        int dtlength = dt.Rows.Count;
                        DataRow[] arr = new DataRow[dtlength];

                        dt.Rows.CopyTo(arr, 0);
                        SQLiteCommand upCmd = new SQLiteCommand(
      @"INSERT OR REPLACE
    INTO
      [Table1](
        [TID],
        [TName],
        [TUtility],
        [TType])values(@TID,@Tname,@TUtility,@TType),conn);
       for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                        {
                            upCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TID", Convert.ToInt32(arr[i]["SNo"]));
                            upCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TName", arr[i]["Utility"].ToString());
                            upCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TUtility", arr[i]["Plantname"].ToString());
                            upCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TType", arr[i]["PlantType"].ToString())
                            da.UpdateCommand = upCmd;

                            this.da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
```

How should I add this TID value in such a way that when the users inserts a new row, it should automatically put the serial number. 
I mean: Suppose there are 4rows currently in the DGV. The DGV is in edit mode(*).I am adding a new row. Once the user tries to enter some data in the new row, there should be a serial number already populated.

Thank you
Sun

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your problem but why not just put NULL for TID when you do INSERT. Since TID is primary key, the sqlite will insert value automatically.

According to [Sqlite FAQ](http://sqlite.org/faq.html#q1) it says this for primary key

> whenever you insert a NULL into that column of the table, the NULL is
>   automatically converted into an integer which is one greater than the
>   largest value of that column over all other rows in the table, or 1 if
>   the table is empty.